# Java Quartz Memory leak message

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

i have an quartz job in my web-application, which is started by an servlet.
When i redeploy my application i get following message

```
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak
```

Also in production we have the problem that the tomcat-server doesn't stop after ./shutdown.sh, so that we have to kill the process. In my opinion it depence on the quartz job, that can't stop.

How can i stop the quartz job by redeploy my application or shutdown the server?

I use tomcat 7, quartz 2.1.6 ...

```
    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

    scheduler.start();

    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(XYZJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1","group1")
                                                 .startNow()
                                                 .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 1 * * ?"))
                                                 .build();

    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

As you can see my job starts one time per day. I don't see an point where i can check an flag, to cancel the job.

Comment: I think this one should be asked on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)(if its a professional system) or [superuser](http://superuser.com). Just a tip if you do not get any answers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to change my configuration. I created an quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = XYZJob
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz-config.xml 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
```

a quartz-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<job-scheduling-data
xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData 
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
version="1.8">

<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>XYZJob</name>
        <group>XYZGroup</group>
        <description>Check the contracts idle period</description>
        <job-class>com.test.job.cron.XYZJob</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>CronTriggerName</name>
            <job-name>XYZJob</job-name>
            <job-group>XYZGroup</job-group>
            <!-- It will run every day at 1 am -->
            <cron-expression>0 0 1 * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

and use the QuartzInitializerServlet in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

After shutdown my Tomcat, i get the following message

```
INFO: QuartzInitializer: Quartz Scheduler successful shutdown.
```

Comment: It's OK, if your job schedule, job duration and shutdown times do not conflict. How long does your job run? And what happens, if the system is shut down, and the job is still running (for a longer time)?

Answer (score 3):

Your job must check regularly (for example, in each iteration), if a shutdown is in progress. 
It's up to you to implement this correctly in your job. Neither Quartz nor Tomcat can help here (how should they stop a thread?).

You could set a flag in a `ServletContextListener`, method `contextDestroyed`.
If the flag is set, the job must finish as soon as possible.

Quartz threads otherwise survive your web application's life time! So an update of your web application does not guarantee that jobs are terminated. I have had zombie jobs waking up "suddenly", right after a new deployment. This is one of the few cases where you just don't believe your log files.

This is why you have to `kill` Tomcat, because there are running threads which have not been created by Tomcat.

Comment: The invocation is fine. The interesting piece of software is the *job* itself. Within the job you should check a "shutdown in progress" flag, and then the job should terminate. There is no safe way to terminate the job from the *outside world*.