# Quartz scheduler with tomcat 8 and spring mvc creates multiple threads and fails to stop when tomcat is stopped

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I have a java spring mvc web application which use Spring 3.2 and Tomcat 8. I use quartz 2.2 to schedule a task. My controller class is:

```
@Controller
public class StatusController  implements Job
{
    @Autowired
    WebContentDefinitionService webContentDefinitionService;


    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException 
    {
         SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
         System.out.println("Starting Job");
        try 
        {
            webContentDefinitionService.deletePurgedContents();
            webContentDefinitionService.moveContentsToPurged();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         System.out.println("Executed Job");

    }

}
```

and I have a QuartzInitializer class as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

@WebListener
public class QuartzListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        super.contextInitialized(sce);
        ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(StatusController.class).build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("simple").withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?")).startNow().build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ctx.log("There was an error scheduling the job.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

My porm.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasicQuartz</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>BasicQuartz</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now everything works fine for me until I try to stop my tomcat server. I get error telling that there are multiple threads started by the quartz initializer, but unable to stop them and this may lead to memory leak.
I found lot of similar instances, but could not find a solution that can be applied in my case since I am not using my `web.xml` file to initialize the quartz scheduler. The error I get on my console is as follows:

```
   Aug 14, 2015 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 14, 2015 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [smartwcm-admin] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Aug 14, 2015 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [smartwcm-admin] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
Aug 14, 2015 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [smartwcm-admin] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you will have to implement something like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394541/java-quartz-memory-leak-message) .This is not exactly same as your situation, but hope it might help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which I solved with the following setting

```
SchedulerFactoryBean.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to shut the Scheduler down, when stopping the application? [Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/) (like other threadpools) has a shutdown() and a shutdown(boolean waitForTasks) method.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with shutdown. The scheduler is shutting down successfully, but the threads created are not getting shut down when tomcat is stoped

Comment: @edwiser ... then the Scheduler is not shutting down. Just like @Stefan said, you need to shut it down yourself. Try implementing a `contextDestroyed` method in your `ServletContextInitializer` -- or, I believe that Spring includes such an `Initializer`... look around.